# Slick 3.0.0 AutoIncrement Composite Key

Tags: slick

I have a table structure as below:

```
Table1:
  id: Int
  name: String
  version: Int
```

The corresponding Slick representation of the table would be:

```
  class Table1(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, Int)](tag, "TABLE1") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID")
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def version = column[Int]("VERSION")

    def pk = primaryKey("pk_a", (id, version))
  }
```

How can I make the version to auto increment for that corresponding id?

I can have elements like:

```
id name version
1  n1   1
1  n2   2
2  xyz  1
3  bmp  1
3  abc  2
```

So the above structure has id's 1 and 3 in versions 1 and 2, I want to have the version auto increment. If there is a feature in-built, I would like to use it. If not, I have to first issue a select, add 1 t the version and create a new record. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you use the select first version, at some point, you will have duplicate key problems. If two queries run at the same time.

Comment: So what could be the best way to do it? I want to refrain from using triggers!

Comment: You can't. You will have to use triggers if you want to garantuee there will be no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use triggers. That way on insert, you can ask [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) or Postgresql to set the value of `version` to the result of a SQL query :

```
select max(version) from Table1 where id = x
```

Comment: I'm using Postgres and since I'm new to Postgres, I have to look up the documentation on how I could set up a trigger!