# Slick 3.0 Insert and then get Auto Increment Value

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have written this code which works perfectly

```
class Items(tag: Tag) extends Table[Item](tag, "ITEMS") {
  def id = column[Long]("ITEMS_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("ITEMS_NAME")
  def price = column[Double]("ITEMS_PRICE")
  def * = (id, name, price) <> ((Item.apply _).tupled, Item.unapply _)
}

object Shop extends Shop{
  val items = TableQuery[Items]
  val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

  def create(name: String, price: Double) : Int = {
    val action = items ++= Seq(Item(0, name, price))
    val future1 = db.run(action)
    val future2 = future1 map {result => 
      result map {x => x}
    }
    Await.result(future2, Duration.Inf).getOrElse(0)
  }
}
```

This code works but the return value is number of records inserted. But I want to return the value of the AutoInc after the insert has been done.

i did google and found few articles

[Slick 3.0.0 AutoIncrement Composite Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421109/slick-3-0-0-autoincrement-composite-key)

[Returning the auto incrementing value after an insert using slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924686/returning-the-auto-incrementing-value-after-an-insert-using-slick)

But somehow these do not answer the question cleanly.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's the [relevant documentation page](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting), according to which, you should construct a query like this:

```
val insertQuery = items returning items.map(_.id) into ((item, id) => item.copy(id = id))

def create(name: String, price: Double) : Future[Item] = {
  val action = insertQuery += Item(0, name, price)   
  db.run(action)
}
```

Comment: +1. I found that [Play-Slick-Silhouette](https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed) Typesafe Activator template is a pretty good introduction how to use Slick 3.0 in a 'real-life' setting, for example [here](https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed/blob/master/app/models/daos/PasswordInfoDAO.scala) and [here](https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed/blob/master/app/models/daos/UserDAOImpl.scala), including the 'return assigned identity' problem.

Comment: If I could give you an upvote of 100+ I would. This is probably the most concise answer to this question I have seen.

Comment: this may be obvious, but I'm new in slick/scala, in what variable the autoincrement column is stored? how to get it?

Comment: @ps0604 The query above constructs an instance of `Item` with the (auto-incremented) id set to 0. When a row is inserted into the database, it creates a *copy* of this instance of `Item`, where the new copy has its id set to, for example, 8 instead of 0 - `(item, id) => item.copy(id = id)`. So, to answer your question, you'll find the autoincremented value in `item.id`.

Comment: where exactly is `item.id`? I don't see any `item` object accessible after you run the action

Comment: @ps0604 `db.run` will return a `Future[Item]` (note the method's signature). After awaiting the future, you'll get an `Item`.

Comment: It will only work if your table has less than 22 columns, because otherwise HLists will replace case classes and there will be no `copy` method.

Comment: having the db.run(action) right there will break transactionality if there is a greater chain of db work going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219200/how-to-use-transaction-in-slick?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 9):

Try this one instead:

```
def create(name: String, price: Double): Future[Int] = db.run {
    (items returning items.map(_.id)) += Item(0, name, price)
}
```