# How to use transaction in slick

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have insert method like this (weight is index)

```
implicit def run[A](action: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, _ <: slick.dbio.Effect]): Future[A] = {
    db.run(action)
  }

def insert(newCategory: CategoryExtractor): Future[Either[String, CategoryResponse]] = {
        category.map(_.weight).max.result.flatMap {
          case Some(weight) =>
            val temp = newCategory.copy(weight = weight+1)
            (category += temp).andThen(DBIO.successful(Right(toCategoryExtractor(temp))))
          case None =>
            val temp = newCategory.copy(weight = 1)
            (category += temp).andThen(DBIO.successful(Right(toCategoryExtractor(temp))))
        }
  }
```

and I call it 2 time

```
insert(CategoryExtractor("1", "name", "scala every where", 0, 0, 0, None)) onComplete {
    case Success(data) => println(data)
  }

insert(CategoryExtractor("2", "name", "haskell every where", 0, 0, 0, None)) onComplete {
    case Success(data) => println(data)
  }
```

and it return exception(Unique index).

How to fix this and I don't use for-comprehension or insert in first onComplete. Just call it 2 time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a common mistake - converting to `Future` to early (in other words calling `db.run(...)` to early).

What you need to do is to remove this method as it (maybe a little unintuitively) brings more harm than good:

```
implicit def run[A](action: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, _ <: slick.dbio.Effect]): Future[A] = {
    db.run(action)
  }
```

Rule of thumb is basically that you usually would like to strictly control you actual database interactions (and transactional boundaries) so I would advice against any kind of `implicit`s in this area. After all it's one of the driving ideas behind this library - `Slick` tries to be very explicit in your interactions between application and db (contrary to classic ORMs - where using accessor might have actually fired lazy call to db or setting a value through mutator might resulted in actual database update).

Then you need to change the return type to this (changed `Future` to `DBIO`):

```
def insert(newCategory: CategoryExtractor): DBIO[Either[String, CategoryResponse]] = {
...
  }
```

and than you do this:

```
val firstInsert = insert(CategoryExtractor("1", "name", "scala every where", 0, 0, 0, None)) map {
    data => println(data)
}

val secondInsert = insert(CategoryExtractor("2", "name", "haskell every where", 0, 0, 0, None)) map {
    data => println(data)
}

db.run(DBIO.seq(firstInsert, secondInsert).transactionally))
```

Basically the thing is: **as soon as you convert `DBIO` to `Future` you loose capability of bundling actions into single transaction.** So you basically do everything with use of different transformations of DBIO (usual stuff: `map`, `flatMap`, `seq` etc) and only as the very last step you fire `db.run(yourComposedDbio.transactionally)`.

EDIT:
Here is some more information about handling transactions and `DBIO` composition from the presentation I gave couple of weeks ago. Relevant slide: http://slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/85 (and further).

Also there is a great workshop run by Dave Gurnell where he talks about this at around: 01:05:00 (link here: https://vimeo.com/148074461 )

Comment: that work and I have a new problem. I have List(dataToUpdate) and I want to update them into database. my code => `db.run((for {
        ns <- DBIO.sequence(a.map(x => category.filter(_.id === x.uuid).update(x)))
      } yield ns).transactionally)` if uuid in list dosen't have in database rollback it. I try to use transactionally but it doesn't rollback for me

Comment: using println(data) as a future handling is not a good example of a real action to perform. You should demo something that does not return a Unit

Comment: Hey @AndrewNorman 
In general I agree. In this particular case I am not sure - the answer tries to mimic question's context as much as possible (println come from question).