# Slick 3: How to implement repository pattern with transactions?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, slick

In my play framework (2.5) app, I need to write unit tests for services.

I need to isolate data access logic to able to test service layer in isolation,
for this I want to create repository interfaces and MOCK them in my unit tests:

```
class UserService {
   def signUpNewUser(username: String, memberName: String): Future[Unit] {
      val userId = 1 // Set to 1 for demo
      val user = User(userId, username)
      val member = Member(memberName, userId) 
      // ---- I NEED TO EXECUTE THIS BLOCK WITHIN TRANSACTION ----
      for {
        userResult <- userRepository.save(user)
        memberRepository.save(member)
      } yield ()     
      // ---- END OF TRANSACTION ----
   }
}
```

In the above example, `userRepository.save(User)` and `memberRepository.save(member)` operations should be performed within transaction.

I don't want to use slick directly in my service layer because it will complicate my tests.

Also, I don't want to use embedded database for my unit tests, elsewhere it would be a NOT unit test, I need complete isolation.

I do not want my repository interfaces to be depended on slick at all, but need something like this:

```
trait UserRepository {
   findById(id: Long): Future[Option[User]]
   save(user: User): Future[Unit] 
}
```

how can I achieve this with slick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK - let's decompose your question into three parts.

**How to execute block in transaction**

Basically read this answer: [How to use transaction in slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219200/how-to-use-transaction-in-slick/41219465#41219465)

As soon as you convert `DBIO` to `Future` you are done. No chances to compose multiple operation within single transaction. End of story.

**How to avoid using `Slick` in tests**

This is basically a design question - if you want to have a business layer on top of `Repository` / `DAO` / whatever - than let this service layer deal with transactions. You won't need to interact with `Slick` outside of this layer.

**Avoiding your repository interfaces to depend on `Slick`**

In most straightforward way - you need to depend on Slick `DBIO` to compose operations within transaction (and composing `Repository` methods within transaction is something that you cannot avoid in any serious application).

If you want to avoid depending on `DBIO` you would perhaps create you own monadic type, say `TransactionBoundary[T]` or `TransactionContext[T]`.

Then you would have something like `TransactionManager` that would execute this `TransactionContext[T]`.

IMHO not worth the effort, I'd simply use `DBIO` which has a brilliant name already (like Haskell's `IO` monad - `DBIO` informs you that you have a description of `IO` operations performed on your storage). But let's assume that you still want to avoid it.

You could do something like that perhaps:

```
package transaction {

  object Transactions {
    implicit class TransactionBoundary[T](private[transaction] val dbio: DBIO[T]) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  class TransactionManager {
    def execute[T](boundary: TransactionBoundary[T]): Future[T] = db.run(boundary.dbio)
  }
}
```

Your trait would look like this:

```
trait UserRepository {
   findById(id: Long): TransactionBoundary[Option[User]]
   save(user: User): TransactionBoundary[Unit] 
}
```

and somewhere in your code you would do like this:

```
transactionManager.execute(
    for {
        userResult <- userRepository.save(user)
        memberRepository.save(member)
    } yield ()  
)
```

By using implicit conversion you would have your results of methods in `Repository` be automatically converted to your `TransactionBoundary`.

But again - IMHO all of the above doesn't bring any actual advantage over using `DBIO` (except perhaps taste of esthetics). If you want to avoid using `Slick` related classes outside of certain layer, just make a type alias like this:

```
type TransactionBoundary[T] = DBIO[T]
```

and use it everywhere.