# Play Scala Slick transactions

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I want to use `transactions` in `Play` `Slick` `Scala`

I have three different methods which returns boolean value

```
def updateFirst() 
def updateSecond()
def updateThird()
```

I am trying to run the below command but it seems `transactionally` command is not found

```
val operations =
  for {
     _ <- updateFirst()
     _ <- updateSecond()
     _ <- updateThird()
  } yield ()

sync(db.run(operations).transactionally))
```

My codebase sbt version related to slick is as below :

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.1",
```

Even DBIO is not showing anything.

Any help or lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624229/2239369

It has been covered multiple times already - you can only compose operations in transaction as long as they return `DBIO[T]` (where `T` is your resulting type). In your case your methods should return:

```
def updateFirst(): DBIO[Boolean] 
def updateSecond(): DBIO[Boolean]
def updateThird(): DBIO[Boolean]
```

Also your last line should be:

```
sync(db.run(operations.transactionally))
```

(`transactionally` is called on `DBIO`, not on `Future` )

Also take a look at following slide: http://slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/85

Comment: How do I convert my method return to DBIO[Boolean]?  THis is sample sync(db.run(query.update(status))) == 1.. I have tried removing sync and other stuffs as well

Comment: Just convert `sync(db.run(query.update(status)))  == 1` to this: `query.update(status).map(_ == 1)`

Comment: Thanks a ton Pawal.

Comment: How can i check whether transaction has completed successfully?

Comment: check it in `recover` method of the `Future` (you should catch exception there if it happened)

Comment: I need some urgent help. If you can give some precious time of yours it will be of much help. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136334/room-for-sourav-ganguly-and-pawel-dolega