# how can i execute or not a line of a for-comprehension depending on a condition, with scala slickdb

Tags: slick-3.0

I have this code using slickdb:

```
val action: DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Effect] =
  for {
    id <- sql"select id from product where name = $name".as[Int].head
    _  <- sql"update product set description = ${description(id, name)}".asUpdate if id != 5
  } yield id

db.run(action)
```

With this code, the action will not return the `id` if `id != 5`. This is not what I want. I want that the `set description` update is only executed if `id != 5`, and at the same time `dbaction` must return the `id` independenting or whether `id != 5` or not.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this:

```
val action: DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Effect] =
  for {
    id <- sql"select id from product where name = $name".as[Int].head

  } yield {
     if (id != 5) {sql"update product set description = ${description(id, name)}".asUpdate }
     id
}
```

Comment: This does not work, because executing `db.run(action)` will not execute the second sql statement. That is, the second sql statement is totally lost and useless.

Comment: Then, you might have to use slick models... as the for loop you first created suffers from the same problem, isn't it? Suggestion: Look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443505/slick-3-0-insert-and-then-get-auto-increment-value