# Get auto-generated ID from INSERT by Slick Plain SQL

Tags: scala, slick

I need to get the auto-increment ID generated by MySQL for my `INSERT INTO xxx ...`.

I know I can get the auto-generated ID for the `INSERT` DML by Slick DSL, as mentioned in the question of [Slick 3.0 Insert and then get Auto Increment Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443505/slick-3-0-insert-and-then-get-auto-increment-value)

But is there any simple solution to get the ID with Slick Plain SQL? I mean `sqlu""" INSERT INTO xxx """`.

Maybe I can perform `INSERT` & `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in a single MySQL transaction to achieve it? But not sure if it's a recommended way.

Is there any single statement solution to ti?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` is _the_ way to get the auto incremented value in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I use the way as `(insertTaskAction andThen selectTaskIdAction).transactionally`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the way as `(insertTaskAction andThen selectTaskIdAction).transactionally`, although `transactionally` may not quite necessary.